# How to import an exported MongoDb query result to MongoDb using Mongo Compass?

Tags: mongodb

I received a MongoDB exported json file, with a document in every line like this:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("5f4f7f8d6f345a1840baf154"), "field":1233444}
```

When I tried to import it in Mongo Compass, it choked on the ObjectId.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? it's a big file.

Comment: For import, your ObjectIds will need to be like `"_id": {"$oid": "5f4f7f8d6f345a1840baf154"}`.  Can you get a better export?

Comment: Or you could use your favorite stream editor to transform your file, like this example using `sed`:  `sed 's/ObjectId(\(.*\))/{"$oid": \1}/' yourExportedFile.json > yourEJSONfile.json`.